# Puppet agent not working without `sudo`

Tags: puppet

I've installed puppet on an Ubuntu 14.04 system.

It works fine when I use:

```
sudo puppet agent -t
```

But:

```
puppet agent -t
```

returns:

```
Warning: Unable to fetch my node definition, but the agent run will continue:
Warning: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read finished A
Info: Retrieving pluginfacts
Error: /File[/home/rescue/.puppet/var/facts.d]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read finished A
Error: /File[/home/rescue/.puppet/var/facts.d]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet://puppet/pluginfacts: Connection reset by peer - SSL_connect
Info: Retrieving plugin
Error: /File[/home/rescue/.puppet/var/lib]: Failed to generate additional resources using 'eval_generate': SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read finished A
Error: /File[/home/rescue/.puppet/var/lib]: Could not evaluate: Could not retrieve file metadata for puppet://puppet/plugins: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read finished A
Info: Loading facts
Error: Could not retrieve catalog from remote server: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read finished A
Warning: Not using cache on failed catalog
Error: Could not retrieve catalog; skipping run
Error: Could not send report: SSL_connect SYSCALL returned=5 errno=0 state=SSLv3 read finished A
```

I tried making puppet a super user with `sudo usermod -aG sudo puppet` but I still get the same results.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is to some degree a work around.

The core problem I was having above was that when puppet would automatically run (to check into master) every 30 minutes it would always fail.

I stopped the service running on ubuntu and instead of using `service puppet start` I used `sudo service puppet start`.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, puppet-agent needs to run using root privileges in open source version.
You can read a little more here (for enterprise version):
https://puppet.com/blog/new-support-for-non-root-agents-puppet-enterprise